failed to install spDataLarge package in R
I tried to install the spDataLarge package in R using three options mentioned here: https://github.com/Nowosad/spDataLarge
But none of them works.
I also tried to update my R version to the most recent version 4.4.2. I changed the RStudio settings below:
Tools -> Global options -> Packages -> Management -> uncheck the box before "Use secure download method for HTTP". -> Ok.
Option 1:
> install.packages("spDataLarge", repos = "https://geocompr.r-universe.dev")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/userName/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://geocompr.r-universe.dev/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://geocompr.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘spDataLarge’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://geocompr.r-universe.dev/bin/windows/contrib/4.4:
  cannot open URL 'https://geocompr.r-universe.dev/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
In download.file(mirrors_csv_url, destfile = mirrors_csv, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'SSL connect error'

Option 2:
> devtools::install_github("geocompr/geocompkg")
Downloading GitHub repo geocompr/geocompkg@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/geocompr/geocompkg/tarball/HEAD'

Option 3:
> install.packages("spDataLarge", repos = "https://nowosad.github.io/drat/", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/userName/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://nowosad.github.io/drat/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://nowosad.github.io/drat/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘spDataLarge’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

But nothings works.
If anyone possibly knows why, would you offer some help? Thank you!

This looks more like a network or firewall issue. Can you access any of those URLs in error messages in your browser? Can you install any R package? Have you, by chance, blocked R & RStudio in your firewall?

Try going to https://geocompr.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/PACKAGES in your web browser to verify you have access. It seems to work fine for me.

The package appears to be at ‘ https://github.com/Nowosad/spDataLarge’ . Have you tried installing from there?

Since you are on Windows, drop reference to 'source' see comment at bottom - Nowasad.
